Which is the first non-positive coefficient in this formal power series?
Statement of question:
Consider
$$
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^n = \sum_{i \ge 0} a_ix^i.
$$
What is the smallest $k$ such that $a_k \le 0$ ?
For example, we can compute the Taylor expansion of this function with a computer as follows:

$n=2$: $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = 1 + x -\frac{3}{4}x^2 + \dots$. Thus, $k = 2$.
$n=3$: $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^3 = 1 + \frac{3}{2}x -\frac{3}{4}x^2 + \dots$. Thus, $k=2$.
$n=4$: $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^4 = 1 + 2x -\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \dots$. Thus, $k=2$.
$n=5$: $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^5 = 1 + \frac{5}{2}x 
+0x^2 + \dots$. Thus, $k=2$.
$n=6$: $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^6 = 1 + 3x +\frac{3}{4}x^2 + x^3 - \frac{45}{16}x^4 + \dots$. Thus, $k=4$.
$n=7$: $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^7 = 1 + \frac{7}{2}x +\frac{7}{4}x^2 + \frac{7}{8}x^3 - \frac{35}{16}x^4 + \dots$. Thus, $k=4$.
$n=8$: $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^8 = 1 + 4x + 3x^2 + x^3 -\frac{13}{8}x^4 + \dots$. Thus, $k=4$.

The sequence of such smallest $k$ for $n \in [2,29]$ reads as
$$
2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10.
$$
And one may conjecture that the pattern is nothing but consecutive even numbers repeating itself 6 times. The question is, can this be shown?
Motivation: This question is motivated by Rains' bound on the minimum distance $d$ of additive self-dual (w.r.t Hermitian-trace inner product) codes in $\mathbb{F}_4^n$. If $a_k < 0$ with $k \le n/2$, in the expansion of $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^n$, then one can conclude that such self-dual codes of minimum distance $k+1$ do not exist. If $a_k = 0$, further investigation is needed. So the resulting sequence of our smallest $k$, will be very close to Rains' bound. But the details of this connection is a story too long to tell.
Reference to Rains' bound: Shadow Bounds for Self-dual Codes, Eric M. Rains, IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON INFORMATION THEORY, VOL. 44, NO. 1, JANUARY 1998
Thank you.

A beautiful question. Essentially if $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{n,k}z^n=(3+\sqrt{1+z})^n$$ and $k_n=\inf{k; a_{n,k}<0}$ then $k_n=2(p+1)$ when $n=6p+r$ for $r=0,1,2,3,4,5.$

Can you find the recurrence relation for the coefficients similar to this other question that you recently asked?

@CalvinLin    Yes, but the recursion is of the form $p(n+2)a_{n+2} = q(n+1)a_{n+1} + r(n)a_n$, where $p,q,r$ are polynomials of degree $2$. I do not know how to proceed further.

I need to get some shut eye soon, but leave the following observations just in case you can make use of them. I have no idea whether this is useful at all. 1) The series of $C(x):=(1-\sqrt{1-4x})/2+1$ is almost the generating function of the Catalan numbers, therefore all its coefficients are positive integers. 2) Hence the same holds for its powers $C(x)^n$. 3) Therefore the coefficients of $C(-x)^n$ must alternate. Observe that $N(x)=C(-x)=(1-\sqrt{1+4x})/2+1$. 4) If $P(x)=(1+\sqrt{1+4x})/2+1$ is your series multiplied by two, then for all $n$ the symmetric sum...

(cont'd) $F_n(x):=N(x)^n+P(x)^n$ is a polynomial of degree $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. This can be seen either by Galois theory of $\Bbb{Q}(x,\sqrt{1+4x})/\Bbb{Q}(x)$ or by using the recurrence. It seems to me that the coefficients of all the polynomials $F_n(x)$ are all positive, but I don't know yet how to prove that.
